# Can I prevent arguments from being passed via NextMethod in R?

Tags: r, oop, subset, argument-passing

I have a subclass of `data.frame` that needs an extra argument when subsetting.  `NextMethod()` passes extra arguments along, which generates an error because the next method recognizes neither the argument itself, nor the 'dots' arguments.

Example:

```
class(Theoph) <- c('special','data.frame')
`[.special` <- function(x, i, j, drop, k, ...){
   y <- NextMethod()
   attr(y, 'k') <- k
   y
}

Theoph[1:5,k='head']
```

Result:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(Theoph, 1:5, k = "head") : 
unused argument (k = k)
```

Can I make 'k' invisible downstream?  I've tried removing it, defining as NULL, passing only arguments of interest, writing a wrapper.  The subset operator `[` is a particularly difficult generic because of some non-default argument matching rules.

Comment: You can call set arguments to the `NexMethod` for example `NextMethod(.Generic, object = x, i = i,j=j, drop = drop)` but for some reason(I don't know ) this give me an invisible output. But genreally speaking, it is better to respect the rule to have the same argument as the generic function

Comment: @agstudy, I had tried this too earlier, but it failed as it seemed all arguments were still being passed through.  The particular failure you're getting (not just invisible, but complete lack of return value) is happening because both `j` and `drop` are missing, so when you call `NextMethod` with `drop` it fails silently.  Try `NextMethod(.Generic, object=x, i=i)` to see what I mean.  This all seems to be an issue with `[` in particular.  I was able to get this to work fine with a normal generic.

Comment: @BrodieG excellent! thanks for the clarification. So I guess that generic primitive are a particular case of generics...

Comment: @agstudy, I think so, but documentation is frustratingly sparse in this area.

Comment: @BrodieG yes you can read [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/The-object-argument-of-NextMethod-td797938.html). Obviously, the definitive documentation in this area is the C code:). Personally I rarely(maybe never) use it.

Answer (score 2):

Since in this case you know what the next method is, why not just call it?

```
class(Theoph) <- c('special','data.frame')

`[.special` <- function(x, i, j, drop = TRUE, k, ...) {
  y <- `[.data.frame`(x, i, j, drop = drop)
  attr(y, 'k') <- k
  y
}

Theoph[1:5, k = 'head']
```

However, I would be cautious about this sort of approach since `[` is a rather special function, and I don't think it actually includes `...` in its argument list. (It looks like it does in the docs, but I think this is a simplification and it's not using the standard `...` object)

Comment: Well! But more generally what is the best practice to "overwrite" primitive generic methods? should I avoid adding extra arguments and use those of generic?

Comment: Hmm, based on the `NextMethod` failure with the missing arguments I just assumed I couldn't do the same with the just calling the function directly, hence the mess in my answer.  There I go for assuming...

Comment: @agstudy I don't think this problem applies to other internal generics because their definitions are usually clearer, and the semantics for their use of ... are better defined.

Comment: Thanks all, for your thoughts!  @hadley:  yes, I tried calling the next method directly, but there are at least three methods downstream, ending in a primitive with non-default argument matching.  I end up having to trap almost every combination of missingness for i, j, and drop.  In particular, x[nms] and x[,nms] are superficially similar in output but require different treatment in code.  I was thinking the 'correct' thing would be to use NextMethod, and modify the environment of that call, if possible.